# Is there a web-standards method of suppressing mailto: linkification?

Tags: hyperlink, gmail, mailto, email-address

When Gmail opens a message containing a bare email address that does not have mailto: link, it "helpfully" turns it into a mailto: link, there is unwanted change of the text styling too.

Is there a web standards tag that authors (such as email newsletter operators) can use to suppress linkification?  On Googling, I see some mention of this idea, `<nolink></nolink>` and `<span class="nolink"></span>`.  But I could not find any authoritative page saying that this is what I should use.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions like:

`My my mail is <a>myname@example.com</a>`

Or

`My my mail is myname<span>@</span>example<span>.</span>com`

But both are tricks, no standards.